# User existence checker not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am doing a register page for a website and i want to check if the user exists then alert the user.
I tried different things and still not working.
Here's my latest code:

```
<?php //script pour vérifier et enregistrer les données


if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //on récupère les données entrées
    $name = ucfirst($_POST['userName']); //mettre le premier caractère en majuscule
    $firstName = ucfirst($_POST['firstName']);
    $birthDate = $_POST['year'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day'];
    $languageM = $_POST['langueM']; //langue maternelle
    $languageE = $_POST['langueE']; //langue étudiée
    $email =  $_POST['mailInput'].'@'.$_POST['schools'];
    $password1 = $_POST['password1'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];


    if(isset($name,$firstName,$birthDate,$languageM,$languageE,$email,$password1,$password2))
    {

        if ($password1===$password2)
        {
            //hashage du mot de passe
            $password1_sha1 = sha1($password1);
            $password2_sha1 = sha1($password2);
            // taille du nom ou du prénom
            if (strlen($name)>25||strlen($firstName)>25)
            {
             print"<span style=\"color:red;\">Nom  ou pr&eacute;nom trop long !</span>";
              exit();//plus la peine de continuer
            }

            else
            {
            //check password length 
                if (strlen ($password1)>25 || strlen ($password1)<6)
                {
                    print "<span style=\"color:red;\">Le mot de passe doit etre entre 6 et 25 caract&egrave;res</span>";
                    exit();
                }
                else
                {

                 //connection à la bdd
                    try
                    {
                        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bladuo', 'root', '');
                        $bdd->exec('SET NAMES utf8');//affichage caractères utf-8 dans la bdd

                        $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                        //enregistrement de l'étudiant dans la bdd
                        $stmt =  $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO membres(nom,prenom,date_de_naissance,langue_maternelle,langue_etudiee,email,passe)
                                            VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
                        $success = $stmt->execute(array($name , $firstName , $birthDate, $languageM , $languageE , $email,$password1_sha1)); 

                        if($success)
                        {
                            header('Location: Index.php');
                        }else

                        {
                            $stmt= $bdd->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM `membres` WHERE nom=?");
                            $stmt->execute(array($name));
                            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                            {
                                $username_count = $row["count"];
                            }
                            //if username is taken    
                            if ($username_count > 0) 
                            {
                                print "<span style=\"color:red;\">Cet utilisateur existe déjà!</span>";
                            }
                            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM `user` WHERE email=?");
                            $stmt->execute(array($email));
                            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
                            {
                                $email_count = $row["count"];
                            }
                            if ($email_count > 0)
                            {
                                print "<span style=\"color:red;\"That email address is already in use<span>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception $e)
                    {
                        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
                    } 
                }

            }

        }else 
        {
            print "<span style=\"color:red;\">Les mots de passe ne sont pas identiques</span>";
            exit();
        }

        }else
        {
            print "<span style=\"color:red;\">une des variables nest pas set</span>";
        }          

}
```

?>

when i try to register an already existing user, it is saved in the database.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you insert the user, then you check if it exist. Do it in reverse order.

Comment: you could also set the specific columns for the user to UNIQUE, so you would get a database error (which you would have to catch) when you try to add the same user a second time.

Comment: @TheChaos you shouldn't really use a DB Exception to give you information, you should really check the data before you send it to the DB.

Comment: @Arth: well it always depends on the use case.. this way you could be assured that the data is always correct without duplicates (even if you try to add users by hand into the database). See it more as an additional security layer to restrict the data. And yes, you should definitely also check it on the application level as well.

Comment: @TheChaos I totally agree.

Comment: Problem solved, i forgot to update the post.thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update the post for those who could have the same problem

```
<?php //script pour vérifier et enregistrer les données


if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //on récupère les données entrées
    $name = ucfirst($_POST['userName']); //mettre le premier caractère en majuscule
    $firstName = ucfirst($_POST['firstName']);
    $birthDate = $_POST['year'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day'];
    $languageM = $_POST['langueM']; //langue maternelle
    $languageE = $_POST['langueE']; //langue étudiée
    $email =  $_POST['mailInput'].'@'.$_POST['schools'];
    $password1 = $_POST['password1'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];


    if(isset($name,$firstName,$birthDate,$languageM,$languageE,$email,$password1,$password2))
    {

        if ($password1===$password2)
        {
            //hashage du mot de passe
            $password1_sha1 = sha1($password1);
            $password2_sha1 = sha1($password2);
            // if user exists
             $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bladuo', 'root', '');
             $bdd->exec('SET NAMES utf8');//affichage caractères utf-8 dans la bdd
             $stmt= $bdd->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM `membres` WHERE email=?");
             $stmt->execute(array($email));
             while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
             {
                $email_count = $row["count"];
             }
             if ($email_count > 0) 
             {
                print "<span style=\"color:red;\">Addresse email déjà utilisée, veuillez en choisir une autre!</span>";
             }

            else
            {
            //check password length 
                if (strlen ($password1)>25 || strlen ($password1)<6)
                {
                    print "<span style=\"color:red;\">Le mot de passe doit etre entre 6 et 25 caract&egrave;res</span>";
                    exit();
                }

                else
                {   
                 //connection à la bdd
                    try
                    {
                        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bladuo', 'root', '');
                        $bdd->exec('SET NAMES utf8');//affichage caractères utf-8 dans la bdd

                        $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                        //enregistrement de l'étudiant dans la bdd
                        $stmt =  $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO membres(nom,prenom,date_de_naissance,langue_maternelle,langue_etudiee,email,passe)
                                            VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
                        $success = $stmt->execute(array($name , $firstName , $birthDate, $languageM , $languageE , $email,$password1_sha1)); 

                        if($success)
                        {
                            header('Location: Index.php');
                        }else

                        {    
                           echo "INSERT a echouer!!";
                           exit();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception $e)
                    {
                        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
                    } 
                }

            }

        }else 
        {
            print "<span style=\"color:red;\">Les mots de passe ne sont pas identiques</span>";
            exit();
        }

        }else
        {
            print "<span style=\"color:red;\">une des variables nest pas set</span>";
        }          

}
```

?>